# What is the relationship between a P-matrix and a positive definite matrix?

Tags: positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Let $M$ be a real matrix.

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-matrix#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20P%2Dmatrix,0.), a P-matrix is a square matrix and all of its principal minors are positive.

On the other hand, people use two different definitions to refer to the positive definiteness.

Def 1) $M$ is a positive definite matrix if $x^TMx>0$ for all $x$.

Def 2) $M$ is a symmetric matrix, and it satisfies the condition $x^TMx>0$ for all $x$.

While I try to study the properties of a P-matrix, I found this lecture note([link](https://www.math.wsu.edu/faculty/tsat/files/PmatricesLectureNotes.pdf)), and it says, on page 5 line 6, that "A positive definite matrix A ∈ Mn(C) is a hermitian P-matrix."

I guess the author uses the second definition of positive definiteness.

If this is the case, can we say $M$ is a P-matrix if and only if $M$ satisfies the condition $x^TMx>0$ for all $x$?

Comment: That's only for real symmetric $M$.  It's easy to find non-symmetric P-matrices $M$ and vectors $x$ for which $x^T M x < 0$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Got it. Thanks!